# Issue with impot/first in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

for some reason my log is saying this:

```
ERROR in [eslint]
src\questions\CompanyAddress.jsx
  Line 6:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 7:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 8:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

Here is the file in question:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/forms.css';
import Banner from '../components/ProgressBar';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';;
import CTA from '../components/CTA';
import { LinkWithQuery } from '../components/BackButton';
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";

function CompanyAddress() {
...
}
```

i have looked and i have no imports other than on top, i have nothing before any imports either, i tried adding the comment eslint-disable import/first and nothing seems to work. What else can i provide to further trouble shoot this

Comment: if u use vscode, try to download eslint extension and in you setting search for code on save go `workspace` in eslint and add following: 

{
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": null,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
      },
      "eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
}

Comment: from the log it seems like just the import order issue

Comment: That was the fix! Thanks!